# Any way to grab a numeric value from a file and add it?

Tags: bash, scripts

Here's a step wise explanation of what I want

1. The script is ran 10 time
2. On typing the command `su -c hackbench -pTl 4000` it'll export a message like `Running in threaded mode with 10 groups using 40 file descriptors each (== 400 tasks) Each sender will pass 4000 messages of 100 bytes Time: 13.353` with differing time in place of 13.353
3. I want to add the `13.353` to the next value of `su -c hackbench -pTl 4000` which for example is `Running in threaded mode with 10 groups using 40 file descriptors each (== 400 tasks) Each sender will pass 4000 messages of 100 bytes Time: 10.476` in order to find the average of 10 runs

I know that it can be looped using a for loop and I even know the time can be added like maybe
`TIME=$(($TIME + $("somehow we have to bring '10.476' here")))`

I just don't know how I can grab ONLY the 13.353 and 10.476

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ su -c hackbench -pTl 4000| awk '{print $NF}'
13.353
```

Awk splits each input line into *fields*.  `$NF` is the last field on the line.

Using grep:

```
$ su -c hackbench -pTl 4000| grep -oE '[[:digit:]+-.]+$'
13.353
```

`-o` tells `grep` to print only the matched content.  `[:digit:]+-.]+$` matches the number at the end of the line.

Using sed:

```
$ su -c hackbench -pTl 4000| sed 's/.* //'
13.353
```

`s/.* //` removes all content on the line up to and including the last space.  Only the final number remains.

Using bash:

```
$ readarray -d' ' arr < <(su -c hackbench -pTl 4000); echo "${arr[-1]}"
13.353
```

This reads the output of the hackbench command into array `arr`.  `${arr[-1]}` prints the last element of the array.  (This requires a recent version of bash.)

#### Adding

Bash does not understand floating point numbers.  So, one must use awk or bc or another tool.  For example:

```
$ time=10
$ time=$(echo "$time + ${arr[-1]}" | bc -l)
$ echo "$time"
23.353
```

As an aside, it is best practice to use lower or mixed-case names for shell variable names in your work.  This is because the system uses upper-case names for its variables and you don't want to accidentally overwrite one of them.